# JOptionPane isn't showing

Tags: java, joptionpane

JOptionPane is not showing.. Please check my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Ok")){
     if ( e.getActionCommand().equals(btnOk) ){
              if(connect(txtUser.getText(), txtPass.getText() ) ) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WARNING", "Valid user!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
              }
              else {
                        System.out.print("Wrong password!");
              }

     }
 }
```

my connect method, please check this.

```
public boolean connect(String usr, String pwd){

     try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                     "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USERS", "root", "root" );
          PreparedStatement ps = 
                  connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT lname, fname FROM employees where fname=? and lname =?" );
          ps.setString(1,usr);
          ps.setString(2,pwd);

         resultSet = ps.executeQuery();


       if(resultSet.next()) {
                return true;
       }

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return false;
 } // end of connect method
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: there are 2 condition in this small piece of code, if they both holds true then and only then JOptionPane will appear.

Comment: Can you verify the action command text & result of the connect method

Comment: It's a little weird how you are using *userName* and *password* as *firstName* and *lastName*. Could you please tell us what you get? Do you get any output at all? Do you get any errors? Did you try debugging to see if it passes the `e.getActionCommand().equals(btnOk)` if statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it does not print *Wrong password!* it means that it does not pass the `e.getActionCommand().equals(btnOk)` line. Make sure `btnOk` is a String and it is the String you are looking for.

If it prints *Wrong password*, it is straighforward why this happens.

`btnOk` sounds like a button to me, not a String (but without any extra code snippets we just have to guess that), so be careful not to test equality between the String actionCommand and a button.

Comment: Yeah I changed it to "Ok". My mistake. But it still didn't show. I have tried many times. I input the correct password but still the same thing happened.

Comment: Define "the same thing". Do you get *WrongPassword*? In that case, the `connect` method does something wrong. Please be more explicit on what you get.